# Why can't my Java program find svm_learn or svm_classify?

Tags: java, eclipse, svmlight, cleartk

I am using ClearTK along with SVM-Light programmatically within Java.  I have downloaded the package both for ClearTK integration as well as for SVM-Light itself.  Whether I run via Eclipse or the command line, I keep getting

`Cannot find file "svm_learn"`

I try putting it in the current directory.  I try putting including its location using "-cp" on the command line or add the folder in Eclipse to the runtime classpath.  What must I do to get my Java code to recognize where the two executables reside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to adjust the $PATH variable for your system to include the location for the two executables.  Only then will eclipse or command line execution pick up these tools.  It is not good enough to do `-cp` or add it to your Eclipse runtime classpath.

Examples include:

```
export PATH=$PATH:{svm light path}
```

for Linux or

```
set PATH=%PATH%;{svm light path}
```

for windows

In addition, if using Eclipse, you may have to go to your environment tab and make sure you reference the system path variable by pushing Select and then selecting Path